# Target specific Router while using Link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an app that looks like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path="/" component={Root} />
</BrowserRouter>

// Root.js
function Root() {
  return (
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={MemRoot} />
      <Route path="/bar">
        <Link to="/>To browser Root</Link>
      </Route>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
}
```

Right now when I click on `Link`, it's going to change the URL of `MemoryRouter`, but I'd actually like it to mutate the URL of `BrowserRouter`.

How can I tell `Link` to target the `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: What's the reason you're using a `MemoryRouter` within a `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: I have a multi-step wizard that gets super easy to manage with the MemoryRouter (because I don't want to change the actual URL)

Comment: Interesting. The problem is even if `rr4` works that way, you have two routes with the same `path='/'`. That's not gonna work. At least use different path. But this whole thing seems weird to me. You can just use component state to show different step of the wizard. "You don't want to change the actual URL", so why bother using a router then?

Answer (score -1):

Alright, you can do this. See the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-25wxrk?file=index.js):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { 
  BrowserRouter, 
  MemoryRouter, 
  Route, 
  Switch, 
  Link 
} from 'react-router-dom';

const Root = props =>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/" render={ () => 
      <div>
        <p>Home</p>
        <button 
          onClick={ props.onOpen }>
          Start Wizard
        </button>
      </div> } />
  </BrowserRouter>;

const MemRoot = props => 
  <div>
    <p>Wizard Home</p>
    <button onClick={ props.onClose }>
      Finish Wizard
    </button>
    <p>
      <Link to='/bar'>/bar</Link>
    </p>
  </div>;

const Wizard = ({ onClose }) =>
  <MemoryRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/bar" render={ () => 
        <div>bar <Link to='/'>/</Link></div> } />
      <Route exact path="/" render={ () => 
        <MemRoot onClose={ onClose }/> } />
    </Switch>
  </MemoryRouter>;

const App = () => 
  <BranchRoute />  


class BranchRoute extends Component {
  state = { out: false }
  handleClose = () => this.setState({ out: true })
  handleOpen = () => this.setState({ out: false })

  render () {
    const { out } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        { out
          ? <Root onOpen={ this.handleOpen }/> 
          : <Wizard onClose={ this.handleClose } /> 
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: That's a workaround that just shifts the routing responsibility to some custom code. Not a solution

Comment: @FezVrasta [Well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWdd6_ZxX8c). When there is no URL change there is no "routing responsibility". I gave a solution based on your weird requirements. Good luck.